# How to compile node.js with additional addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm relatively new to node.js and I have a question about compiling node.js with additional native module. Is there a way to integrate an addon to node.js so that it is ready for use after compile?

node.js source code is [here](https://github.com/joyent/node). Some built-in libraries are located in deps/

There is a [tutorial](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) for compiling C++ addon as a module of node.js. After compilation of the module a file "myaddon.node" is generated that can be used with require in node.js application.

Is there a way to make the module built-in? I mean I can just compile it together with node.js source code and then deploy to a target machine. So that I can just call

```
var myaddon = require("myaddon");
```

without having to run npm install. There are natives modules such as zlib, http, fs that are integrated into node.js.

I found one [article](http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/10/writing-your-first-native-module-for-node-dot-js-on-windows/) where a native module is built for node.js on Windows using Visual Studio. Is there a similar way to build node.js with your own module on Linux?